# Power Query & Odata.Feed "How can i add a Parameter to source query?"

Tags: powerbi, odata, powerquery

I am creating a Power Query connection via Odata.Feed and i need to insert a parameter (DateTimeZone.LocalNow).

```
OData.Feed("https://test.test?$filter=Test eq '1969' and WhseTaskConfWhseTmznDate  ge datetime'2023-06-28T10:20:00'&$select=Activity", null, [Implementation="2.0"])
```

I would like to include a parameter so that i just get the today's Data and not all.

Any Idea how to set the Parameter and include it to the source code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about

```
 x = OData.Feed("https://test.test?$filter=Test eq '1969' and WhseTaskConfWhseTmznDate ge datetime'
   "&DateTime.ToText(DateTime.LocalNow(), [Format="yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss", Culture="en-US"])&"
  '&$select=Activity", null, [Implementation="2.0"])
```

EDIT

to pick up a date that is not today, for example one day back

```
Date.AddDays(DateTime.LocalNow(),-1)
```

or use a variable

```
Date.AddDays(DateTime.LocalNow(),VariableDays)
```

where you define that name in an earlier step as

```
VariableDays= Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="rangenamehere"]}[Content]{0}[Column1],
```

and have set up a defined range name caleld **rangenamehere** in the excel file that contains a number you will pull in

Comment: Hi Horseyride

Thanks a lot for the help. It works so. I just will include "-1" in order to calculate the day before.

Have a great day and thanks a lot again

Comment: Hi Horseyride.

Is it possible to make you a question? i was trying to create the same parameter but for yestarday and a few day before. 

Could you maybe help me. I will pay you some for each parameter. What do you think?